# Can a local webserver invoke a local browser?

Tags: rust, browser

I have a Rust server which serves pages on http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Is there a cross-platform way of invoking the default browser, with this URL, when the server is started by the user?

On Windows and Ubuntu, I would like the user to double click my server's desktop icon.  This would both start the server and point their browser at http://127.0.0.1:8000.

(Whatever Mac users normally do to launch a program should also work in the same manner.)

Comment: Fork a [subprocess](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html)?

Comment: If possible, the best option would be to do it at a higher level, not directly within the executable you are creating. On Ubuntu, a double click can run a shell script to start the server and open the browser.

Comment: https://docs.rs/webbrowser/latest/webbrowser/